# RESTful webservice returning Unsupported Media Type for POST requests

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, media-type

I have been working on a RESTful webservice using Jersey. I have created my first service and now I am attempting to send requests.  Here is my single POST method:

```
@POST
@Path("getQuote")
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD )
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getQuote(
        @FormParam("effectiveTime") String effectiveTime,
        @FormParam("responseType") String responseType,
        @FormParam("transform") String transform,
        @FormParam("data") String data,
        @FormParam("dataType") String dataType,
        @FormParam("source") String source) {

    String output = "";
    try {
        Map<String, String> formParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        formParams.put("effectiveTime",effectiveTime);
        formParams.put("responseType",responseType);
        formParams.put("transform",transform);
        formParams.put("data",data);
        formParams.put("dataType",dataType);
        formParams.put("source",source);
        //do stuff
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        output = "Error";
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

I have a HTML test form I can use to send data, and have checked the content type is correct using a RequestBin. Here are some of the headers from the request:

```
Host: requestb.in
Content-Length: 16176
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I have tried the following content types with no luck:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD )
& unspecified (no @Consumes annotation)
```

I am unsure how to debug this request. I have tried using curl to test as well with the following params:

```
curl --data "effectiveTime=1o1o1&dataType=lolo&data=lololol&transform=&responseType=lolol" http://localhost:8080/services/ahrdi/getQuote
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eclipse was re using the original war without any alterations as I had not refreshed my project after running mvn compile war:war

I ran mvn clean, refreshed my project in the project browser, ran mvn compile war:war and my restarted the server and requests are now accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try to set the media type header with curl

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "effectiveTime=1o1o1&dataType=lolo&data=lololol&transform=&responseType=lolol" http://localhost:8080/services/ahrdi/getQuote
```

Comment: this returned the same thing , i also tried changing content to JSON and accepting JSON in content type with no luck.

Comment: Does it help if you set consume to wildcard? Can you debug?

Comment: Wildcard does not work either, I am running in Eclipse with Tomcat7 but unsure of where to set breakpoints as my request is not being called